# Gvim gives warning: 'Unable to register window with path'

Tags: vim, gvim

When I open gvim to edit a file, after about 10 or 15 seconds, the terminal window from which I typed `gvim foo.txt` gives the error:

```
** (gvim:2581): WARNING **: Unable to register window with path '/com/canonical
/foo/3C00024': Timeout was reached
```

This doesn't prevent me from continuing to edit with vim, but makes me think something isn't configured correctly. What does this mean?

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, and I've installed Vim with `apt-get install vim vim-gnome vim-nox` etc. (Not sure exactly which packages.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the menus (File, Edit, Tools, Syntax, Buffers, Window, Help) will not be displayed on hovering at the top of the screen when the gvim window is the active window.

It is a [bug](http://fossplanet.com/f10/%5Bbug-771810%5D-%5Bnew%5D-gvim-occasionally-shows-error-unable-registerwindow-path-timeout-reached-138798/) and has a [work around](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dbusmenu/+bug/733265/comments/13).

```
gvim(){ /usr/bin/gvim -f "$@" & true; }
```

Comment: The problem with this workaround is, that "you have running jobs" when try closing the shell while leaving gvim open. At least when you use the zsh. So try this when using zsh: `gvim(){ /usr/bin/gvim -f "$@" & true;disown }` and I didn't observed this error message without loss of any comfort.

Comment: Could you possibly also mention that that line should go in the shell preferences file (maybe mention a few, ie. `.bashrc`)